# PHP - Iterate through multiple lines/rows when uploading CSV

Tags: php, sql, csv, counter

I have a current upload page where I'm uploading CSV files and they are imported into a database. It works great as far as importing and then splitting to the other tables, but the one issue is that it only imports the first line in the CSV. The current test file has 6 rows that should all be imported on one upload. I feel like this would either use a counter (++) or something with a line break (/n). Here is the main loop for the upload before my SQL statements:

```
for($tableno = 0;$tableno < sizeof($tablenames);$tableno++){
$q = "";
$q2 = "";
$q3 = "";
$q4 = "";
$q5 = "";
$q6 = "";
$col_list = '`'.str_replace(',','`,`',$table_cols[$tableno]).'`';
$q .= "INSERT INTO ".$tablenames[$tableno]." (".$col_list.") VALUES (";
$last_id = mysqli_insert_id($connect);
$cols = explode(",",$table_cols[$tableno]);
$data = array();
foreach($cols as $key => $fldname) {
    $data[] = "'".$coldata[$fldname]."'";
}
```

UPDATE
Here is the code for the CSV read:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

$file = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
$filesop = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",");

$coldata = array();

$coldata[ "orderNumber" ] = $filesop[0];
$coldata[ "place" ] = $filesop[1];
```

I'm a little foggy on where the call would need to be to break the lines after the last column of each row.

Comment: where is your code for csv reading ??

Comment: Just edited/updated with that code, which has the first 2 column array elements (though there are 200 total)

Comment: What database you are using?

Comment: please use parameters when inserting data. also learn to read the docs: "fgetcsv — Gets __line__ from file pointer and parse for CSV fields" - php.net/fgetcsv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first example on the [PHP documentation for fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) shows how you loop through lines in the file, and fields in the line.

```
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    // This loops through the lines
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $row++;
        // This loops through the fields
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

UPDATE:

Using some snippets from your posted code, this builds a [multi-insert statement](https://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysql-insert-multiple-records/) from your input file. It assumes fields in `$col_list` and corresponding fields in your csv file are in the same order.

```
$q .= "INSERT INTO {$tablenames[$tableno]} ({$col_list}) VALUES "
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $rows[] = " ( '" . implode( $data, "','" ) . "' )";
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
$q .= implode( $rows, "," );
```

It's untested, but at the end of it `$q` should look something like

> INSERT INTO example
>     (example_id, name, value, other_value)
>   VALUES
>     (100, 'Name 1', 'Value 1', 'Other 1'),
>     (101, 'Name 2', 'Value 2', 'Other 2'),
>     (102, 'Name 3', 'Value 3', 'Other 3'),
>     (103, 'Name 4', 'Value 4', 'Other 4');

Of course you're reading a CSV file in to individual fields, and then essentially concatenating them back in a to a CSV list to insert. It might be easier, if they are properly escaped in the source file, to just use [fgets](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php) within parentheses for the insert.

**Note** you will want to do some data sanitizing and escaping before inserting into your db.

Answer (score 1):

You're reading one line from the file pointer - you need to iterate over the lines until you hit EOF. The [docs](http://php.net/fgetcsv) clearly state:

> fgetcsv() returns NULL if an invalid handle is supplied or FALSE on other errors, including end of file.

so you need to do something like `while($returnResult !== false){.....}`

Comment: I see now. I'm working on putting that in my existing code but I would essentially make a while loop right under my 'fgetcsv' code that says while $fgetcsv != false then break with /n until end of file? I"m reading through the doc, the only confusing thing is my code already loops through the fields, it just stops at the end of line one.

Comment: It does, but it kinda looks like you're working a bit upside down. We don't have the rest of your code, but it looks like you're iterating through a list of table column names and trying to reference matching fields from the CSV file, rather than looping through the CSV fields and then inserting them in to appropriate table columns for the INSERT statement. I will update my answer using your code snippets.

Comment: Thank you. And that's true, I named each column array element  to match the MySQL database since the CSV is uploaded multiple times daily, always in the same order